# Can’t change directory in package.json

Tags: node.js, package.json, chdir

I have a line in my package.json

`"deploy": "yarn build && cd ../../..`

build script that should change directory (`cd ../../..`) after running the first command `(yarn build)`. However, this doesn't seem to trigger changing directory to the root of the project. I have also tried using a separate node task to do so using `process.chdir('../../..');` or `process.cwd('../../..');`, but these don't work either.

I've also tried using a separate node.js file (changedirectory.js) with the following to change directory in my build command `"deploy": "yarn build && node changedirectory.js && cf login`:

```
try {
    process.chdir('../../../');
    console.log(`New directory: ${process.cwd()}`);
} catch (err) {
    console.error(`chdir: ${err}`);
}
```

This does show the correct new directory in terminal, but doesn't actually change the working directory.

Is there something I'm missing or can this not be done with node?

Comment: Windows or Linux? Also, npm runs scripts in a sub shell, so the directory change will have no effect on your current shell session.

Comment: OSX. So there's no way to do this through a node script?

Comment: Oh yeah, there is also OSX :). You can change the directory _within_ the script but this will not have any effect _outside_ the script.